# Maintain concurrency in the user session

Tags: django, python-3.x, function

BY A NOVICE PROGRAMMER:
Web application is being used with RFID card reader (as keyboard emulator).
When the user scans the RFID card in the specific field, RFID reader pastes the card number and then hits enter by itself so that the form is submitted.
Sometimes the user scans the card once and the reader detects it 2 times (contacted vendor but the reader does not support redetection delay kind of a thing).
So on the backend, I have a view function which is executed when the user's form is submitted. From the view function, the card number is send to other 2-3 functions in order to complete all the processes.
I checked the app logs and found that When the card is read 2 times, only 7-8 lines of code is being executed and before the condition is checked, due to scanning card 2nd time, the same functions are called again and the condition checking does not makes sense.

What is the technical term which I should google in order to execute all the functions one by one without any interruption?

Tried using conditions but did not work

Comment: This isn't very clear. If the card is scanned twice, the function will be called twice. But each call will complete, it won't be interrupted by the subsequent one

Comment: @DanielRoseman I also expect the same to happen but it does not.